# Cassandra object mapping annotations with Datastax Java driver

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I am trying to use object mapping annotations with  Datastax Cassandra driver (cassandra-driver-core v. 2.1.0 rc1) According to Datastax documentation this version of the driver supports object mapping similar to JPA:  http://datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/2.1/java-driver/reference/crudOperations.html 
The whole com.datastax.driver.mapping package is missing from the driver's jar. Am i missing something? Do I need an additional dependency for the mapping annotations?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you need the cassandra-driver-mapping artifact:
http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.datastax.cassandra%7Ccassandra-driver-mapping%7C2.1.0-rc1%7Cbundle

Just add the following to your POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @MrkK Accept the answer instead of writing a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Not a different answer from adam, but contains, how-to. :)

Next time for such question OP can use :  http://search.maven.org/

This will result to (as Adam subtly pointed to )   http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.datastax.cassandra%7Ccassandra-driver-mapping%7C2.1.0-rc1%7Cbundle